# Simplify calculation of months between 2 dates (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, date, postgresql-9.1

This question is asked many times and one of the suggested queries to get months between 2 dates is not working.

```
SELECT date_part('month',age('2016-06-30', '2018-06-30'))
```

The result of this query is 0. It should be 24 months. Because the months are 06 in both dates.

This works, but it is a bit clumsy compared to the sql server function:

```
SELECT date_part ('year', f) * 12 + date_part ('month', f) 
FROM age ('2016-06-30', '2018-06-30') f
```

Like sql server (I think):

```
DATEDIFF(month, date1, date2)
```

Is there no simple way (like the above) to calculate the months between 2 dates in Postgresql? I prefer not to use a function if it is possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think POSTGRES provides a simple way of finding Month difference between two dates, your way is fine, you can also look here -> http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff . What is the issue? Is your query slow?

Comment: The possibility of creating custom functions is a powerful feature, aversion to use them is difficult to understand.

Comment: @klin not very hard actually.  the OP is asking if there is a base feature to do this not if it is possible to create this feature.  They are not *necessarily* saying they wont use a function but stating that "use a function" isn't a valid answer to a question asking for a base feature.

Comment: @PhilipCouling - I didn't write *a valid answer to a question* but a comment.

Comment: @klin you wrote that it was hard to understand and I explained it for you

Comment: Using custom function when dealing with 500+ databases is not the first option I think of. I just want to explore all possibilities before doing this. Any tip of how creating a custom function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you already have the most elegant solution.

If you look at the documentation for `extract` (same as `date_part`):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

> month
>
> For timestamp values, the number of the month within the year (1 - 12) ; for interval values, the number of months, modulo 12 (0 - 11)
>
> ```
> SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
> Result: 2
>
> SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM INTERVAL '2 years 3 months');
> Result: 3
>
> SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM INTERVAL '2 years 13 months');
> Result: 1
> ```

For your problem it would be nice if there was a version of `month` that wasn't modulo 12 but that doesn't exist.

The option you have (extract the year * 12 + month) is the best option there is.

---

**Edit**

If you do want to create a function then see the following two functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_months(i interval) RETURNS double precision AS $$
    SELECT date_part ('year', i) * 12 + date_part ('month', i) ;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;


SELECT get_months(age('2016-06-30', '2018-06-30'));
```

Or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_months(to_date date, from_date date) RETURNS double precision AS $$
    SELECT date_part ('year', f) * 12 + date_part ('month', f) 
      FROM age (to_date, from_date) f;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;


SELECT get_months('2016-06-30', '2018-06-30');
```

You can actually create both then just use whichever suits your code.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the # of months between two dates excluding days.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_months_between(to_date date, from_date date) RETURNS double precision AS $$
    SELECT (date_part ('year', to_date) * 12 + date_part ('month', to_date)) - (date_part ('year', from_date) * 12 + date_part ('month', from_date))

$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```